# ReactiveMongo: Need to convert java.time.LocalDate to reactivemongo.bson.BSONDateTime

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

My requirement is to set `BSONDateTime` to specific data only. From `java.util.Date` i found exact data, but when trying to convert in `BSONDateTime` my output is wrong. Following is my code for convert:

```
val currentDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now();
val milliSeconds: Long = currentDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
new BSONDateTime(milliSeconds);
```

**Output**:

**Aspected**: Fri Oct 16 2015 00:00:00

**Actual**: Fri Oct 15 2015 18:30:00

**Update Question**

My Basic requirement is that, i want set and compare my date in mongodb data using query. Like: my mongodb document have following structure

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("561e62892d0000e98ec782c3"),
 "addedOn" : ISODate("2015-10-14T14:11:21.361Z"),
 "expiredOn" : ISODate("2015-10-30T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

*My First Query requirement* is set expire date to current date using below code:

```
 def currentDateOnly: BSONDateTime = {
  val currentDate: LocalDate = LocalDate.now();
  val milliSeconds: Long = currentDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();

  logger.info("currentDateOnly Conversion: "+currentDate); 
  new BSONDateTime(milliSeconds);
}
```

From this code, i found current date with 12 am morning time. I am converting date to `milliSeconds` and create `BSONDateTime` object and set the value using reactive mongo query as below:

```
$set(propertyName -> CustomUtility.currentDateOnly) // this is just a set par of update statement.
```

*My Second Query requirement* is to match "expiredOn" date using following query:

```
$doc("expiredOn" $gte CustomUtility.currentDateOnly);
```

Now, when i set the date in database, my mongo db store invalid value of date, that i also mention above like:

**Output**:

**Aspected**: Fri Oct 16 2015 00:00:00

**Actual**: Fri Oct 15 2015 18:30:00

I need to store specific data and compare query with specific date.

Comment: No sure that's related to `BSONDateTime` itself. If you print `new java.util.Date(milliseconds)`,is that right.If not there is time conversion issue before.

Comment: @cchantep Actual: `Fri Oct 15 2015 18:30:00` value is shown in mongodb.

Comment: What I'm asking, is what you get with the `new Date` & `milliseconds`

Comment: @cchantep please check updated question.

Comment: You still doesn't try the suggested test

Comment: @cchantep ok, i will try, actual now i somewhere, but related this i will notify you.